# How to validate a date with 3 input fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, date, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 3 input fields: year, month and day. I want to validate that the entered date is valid. For example, if someone enters "2016-02-31", an error should be returned.

My problem is that i can't use 1 input field for a `DateTime`, because the end-user needs to enter a lot of dates, and with 3 inputs, he enters them a lot faster, because he can navigate to the next input field using the TAB key on his keyboard faster.

Or if someone has a better solution, i would be happy to hear it.

EDIT: I need client and server side validation.

Comment: Are you wanting client side validation as well as server side validation?

Comment: Yes i need both. Will add to my question. Thanks.

Comment: You could create a `ValidationAttribute` that implements `IClientValidatable` and include scripts to add the rules to the `$.validator` although it may be simpler to just write you own script (that creates a javascript date from the values) and display a message, and in the server, construct a `DateTime` from the 3 values and test if its valid). I'm not sure why you think that having 3 controls and pressing the tab key is easier than one control and pressing the `-` key to create a valid date

Comment: @StephenMuecke i said the same thing to the end-user, but he said that he's much faster this way. That the minus key is harder to press when fast-typing. I tried to convince him, trust me. :D

Comment: @StephenMuecke i will take a look at the things you mentioned, thank you.

Comment: The best way to handle this depends on a few other factors. Do you have a view model with properties `int Year`,`int Month` and `int Day` as well as another property for `DateTime Date`. And how are you generating the controls in the view (using a `for` loop for a collection of that model?)

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to start with a view model to represent your dates

```
public class DateVM
{
    public DateVM() { } // default constructor required by the DefaultModelBinder
    public DateVM(DateTime date) // useful if your editing existing dates
    {
        Date date.Date;
        Day = date.Day;
        Month = date.Month;
        Year = date.Year;
    }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The values for the date are not valid")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and then the main view model would contain a `public List<DateVM> Dates {get; set; }` property.

While it would be possible to create a custom `ValidationAttribute` that implements `IClientValidatable`, (refer [The Complete Guide to Validation-in-ASP.NET-MVC-3 Part-2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) for a good guide to implementing one) it presents a few design problems such as which property do you apply the attribute to?, what happens when one of the other properties is not edited? etc.

Instead, I recommend you just include your own scripts to handle the `.change()` events of each control and validate the date (and display an error message if appropriate), and also handle the forms `.submit()` event to cancel the post if invalid.

Your part of the view for editing the dates would need to be

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Dates.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="date-container">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dates[i].Year)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Dates[i].Year, new { @class = "year" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Dates[i].Year)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dates[i].Month)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Dates[i].Month, new { @class = "month" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Dates[i].Month)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dates[i].Day)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Dates[i].Day, new { @class = "day" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Dates[i].Day)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Dates[i].Date, new { @class = "date" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Dates[i].Date, null, new { @class = "validation" })
    </div>
}
```

and then include the following scripts

```
$('.day, .month, .year').change(function () {
    var container = $(this).closest('.date-container');
    var day = Number(container.find('.day').val());
    var month = Number(container.find('.month').val());
    var year = Number(container.find('.year').val());
    if (isNaN(day) || isNaN(month) || isNaN(year) || day === 0 || month === 0 || year === 0) {
        container.find('.date').val('');
        return;
    }
    var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    var isValid = date.getDate() === day && date.getMonth() === month - 1 && date.getFullYear() === year;
    if (isValid) {
        container.find('.date').val(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
        container.find('.validation').text('').addClass('field-validation-valid').removeClass('field-validation-error');
    } else {
        container.find('.date').val('');
        container.find('.validation').text('The values for the date are not valid').addClass('field-validation-error').removeClass('field-validation-valid');
    }
});

$('form').submit(function () {
    $.each($('.date'), function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            return false;
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: But what about the server side validation?

Comment: It gives you server side validation on everything because your also posting back a DateTime (the hidden input), and if it cannot be parsed to a `DateTime`, a validation error will be shown

Comment: One thing you could do (in the rare case a user might have disabled javascript in their browser) is if the value of `Date` is `null`, then generate a new `DateTime` - `model.Date = new DateTime(model,Year, model.Month, model.Day);` - and if its valid, then remove the `ModelState` error

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far I know You must create your own custom validator.

Look google for more information about `ValidationAttribute`, `IClientValidatable` and - in your case - also `IValidatableObject`.

Few examples:

- [MVC Custom Validation by DataAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100300/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-by-dataannotation)
- [Custom Validation with IValidatableObject in MVC](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/custom-validation-with.html)
- [Custom Unobtrusive Client Validation](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation/)
- [Creating Custom Validation Attribute](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/creating-custom-validation-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc)
- [Creating Custom Validation Attribute in MVC 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC)

Look also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937283/asp-net-whats-the-best-way-to-validate-3-drop-downs-boxes-that-are-used-to-sel?rq=1)

Other way - you can consider using date-picker control instant of three fields. Date-picker gives you easy way to date validation plus few interesting features.

Try this one: [eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) (also available via bower).